# Finding Column Labels corresponding to specific columns in sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, struts2

I am facing problem, finding out specific column names. I am using SQL Server 2005 and am coding in struts 2 framework.

Here is what needs to be done:

I want to find out the column names which have a particular value in a particular row.

**For example**:
In a row in employee table, if the value of a particular column is "true", I want to know the column name.

I know in SQL server we can access all the column names of a table using this query:

```
select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'table's name'
```

but I am not able to fulfill my purpose.

I guess I have defined my issue clearly, if there is anything that I missed out please tell.

Thanks!!

Comment: So you know the table you want to search and you know the columns in the table so this doesn't need to be dynamic then?

Comment: @Martin: yes this is not dynamic. I know the table name and column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you're not using an ORM, and that you're using JDBC, although unfortunately you don't say *how* you're getting data from the database.

You need to use [`ResultSetMetaData` if you're using JDBC.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) from which you can [get the name of a column by its index](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnName%28int%29).

Comment: Hi Dave, I am still new to stack overflow so was not aware of this thing. Will keep that in mind now. thanks!!

Comment: I am using hibernate, but only at places where jdbc would not work. That is because I am new to struts2 and found hibernate a little complicated. So although I am open to both solutions, but would prefer jdbc one just for the sake of simplicity. I will look into ResultSetMetaData now. Thanks!!

Comment: By the way I just found out, in the privileges I have on stack Overflow I cant vote up an answer :(.

Comment: Used This --->>ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
            ResultSetMetaData rsMetaData = rs.getMetaData();
            int colCount = rsMetaData.getColumnCount();
            rs.next();
            int i=1;
            while(i<=colCount){
                if(rs.getString(i).equals("true")){
                    List.add(rsMetaData.getColumnName(i));
                }
                i++;
            }

-----Working as I wanted. Thanks Dave!!

Comment: But I am still interested in the hibernate method.

Comment: Yeah I can, I know that now :). And now I can also rate up a comment :).

Comment: For hibernate, since you know all the columns, hence the model's accessor names, you can just check each column/property. If you want to do it via metadata, start with [ClassMetadata](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/metadata/ClassMetadata.html).